# What is the simplest way to set up a mail server?

Tags: email, domain-server

The fact is: I need to get somehow an email adress like "admin@exampledomain.net"

I tried a couple of tutorials that screwed my server and i had to reset it;

So: How to setup it in the simplest way?

Yes, i own a server (Ubuntu 13.04 x86_64)
Yes, i also own mydomain.net

(Given that my domain is "exampledomain.net", my hostname is "exampledomain", will this give problems? cause it gave me lots)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is subjective, so I will propose some possible solutions based on a couple assumptions:

1. You are trying to learn how to manage an email server to further your education. This is assumed because if you don't know how to set one up you probably don't know [the long list of reasons why you probably shouldn't run your own mail server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/why-you-may-not-want-to-run-your-own-mail-server).
2. You are aware of services like G Suite, which are reliable, cost efficient and robust in terms of management tools and decided they don't meet your needs even though they cost less money to run than your own server.
3. You understand that there are different ways to setup mail servers, and those ways come with unique pros and cons. So while some methods are simpler than others, you ultimately need to consider the pros and cons before you can choose the simplest of those options.

## My Preferred Method

My preferred method is to [install Webmin & Virtualmin](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-webmin-on-ubuntu-16-04), which provide a GUI for email server management (among many other things) once they're installed. It's well documented, well maintained, allows you to use the GUI or CLI seamlessly and without repercussion. It installs all of the necessary software to run a basic web server and does a good job of guiding even the most novice through the process.

## Others

There are many other ways, such as using pre-built servers via services from providers like Digital Ocean.

And on the more complex side of things, you can use services like Vagrant and the respective Vagrant Playbooks that automatically deploy and configure such systems for you. But I suspect that's well beyond what you're looking for even though it definitely simplifies the process if you're running a professional email server.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to setup a fully working email server in Ubuntu, using sane defaults, is to install the *mail-server task*. This can be done using graphical tools, but none that come with Ubuntu by default. Synaptic has a way to do it, for instance, but it will take more time and is much more complicated to explain, so I'll simplify.

1. If you're in Ubuntu desktop, open a terminal by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>
2. Install the `tasksel` package by entering `sudo apt-get install tasksel`
3. Install the mail server task by entering `sudo tasksel install mail-server`

You'll be guided through the install and it should be easy to follow the instructions. You will be asked to enter the domain you wish the mail server to handle, for instance.

Comment: So am i forced to use GUI or does it have a shell-only version to install?

Comment: It is a shell-only solution. The first step was just in case you didn't know how to open a terminal.